# Showing unicode character in java text component

Tags: java, unicode, text, view

I have found that firefox has excellent support for showing unicode text correctly. But when I copy and paste the same characters(in Bengali) in a java text component (such as JTextArea), the output is not same. 
Can anyone please explain me i)what are the issues associated with it and ii) How can I show the unicode text in a java text component correctly.

I am currently using java 6 and I have also installed font for Bengali. My operating system is Mac OSX(10.6). The input can be from other unicode scripts also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which font do you have set for the JTextArea?

The problem is that the font that you have set for the JTextArea can not handle Bengali fonts. There are 2 solutions:

1. Set your font that can show Bengali as the font of the JTextArea.
2. Use a logical font like Dialog or SansSerif which merge multiple fonts. The problem is that this logical fonts use only fonts which are installed by default. I think by default there is no Bengali font installed. You can change this by modify the fontconfig.properties of your Java VM. You need to set that the chachters that are in the Bengali range must display from your font.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate a more. How can i identify that the font support all the characters or how to set the the chachters that are in the Bengali range must display from my font? Any point to good resource will be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that this is different for the different Java versions. In the root directory of your Java you find a file fontconfig.properties or equals. Search on Google how you can edit it. If you want check if a font can display a specific character there is a method isDisplayable(char) or equals.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`